# A number with contraction - is it valid?

Tags: contractions

While contractions go without any doubt with words, I wonder whether they are okay with numbers/digits too!

Are these valid contractions?

> USD **80'll** be paid by me 
>   GBP **1000's** not a small amount 
>  INR **300're** born by my company

I could not find any example. Kindly help me with that. Quote some references.

Comment: The fact you could not find any examples pretty much answers the question.

Comment: Ah, well said @user3169 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No contraction is acceptable in writing with figures.

When numbers are written as words, you may see contractions in informal writing: *Two's company, three's a crowd,* *Seven's my lucky number*.